# My hosting provider allows me to see the names of all other databases on their servers, is this bad practice?

Tags: security, sql-server, hosting, privacy

I've got MSSQL DB functionality set up with a hosting provider, and recently logged in for the first time.  When I added the connection, it then listed (apparently) every single MSSQL database on their servers.  I couldn't access them, but I could see their names, which led me to identifying the related websites.  Is this bad practice?

Comment: This is bad, very bad. The DB Police will be around shortly. Yes your correct this is bad pratice and has huge Data Protection issues.

Comment: Run Forrest! Run like the wind!

Comment: Do YOU care that your mssql db is seen now by the rest of the clients?  When you see the smoke are you going to wait until the fire?

Comment: @andrewb - he wasn't mocking you. Rather he was invoking a quote from a popular movie as a means of communicating how bad this situation is. Regarding your question - you are using shared hosting and as such are not the system administrator. You are a system user. Not that there's anything wrong with that - you're just not the target audience for ServerFault.

Comment: @EEAA and in said popular movie, Forrest is a disabled and completely clueless guy.  Who am I in his analogy?  3 out of 5 responses have been a heavily sarcastic take at my apparent (yet non-existent) paranoia - all I asked was "Is this bad practice?".  There's much better ways of dealing with novice off-topic questions.  Looking at the meta it appears that you guys have been concerned about site health, maybe try being friendlier as that'd encourage me to come back when I have some legitimate and advanced questions.

Comment: That wasn't mocking, that was British Humour.

Comment: @andrewb - yours is a borderline case regarding its appropriateness - I actually think it's relevant and reusable to document than no, this is far from best practice, in fact I'd go nuts with your provider. That said I would like your thoughts on my contention that we might be unfriendly but we consider it unfriendly of new users to ignore all written directions about what and who the site is - it happens SO much, new users think the site should fit their problem, never the opposite. As a new user I'd be interested in your thoughts as we're keen to clarify the purpose of the site.

Comment: @Chopper3 that would be great, how should we best do this?  Chat or meta?  I think it would be best to move it out of this comment block.

Comment: Either would be good, cheers.

Comment: @Chopper3 I added a chat, you able to find it?  If not I may just make a question on meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an unavoidable artifact of being on *shared* web hosting: The resources are *shared* between clients without much isolation.

If it's of particular concern to you, for privacy or other reasons, you should not use shared web hosting.

Comment: No other shared host I've been on let me see *every single database* on the system. Sounds like a configuration issue

Comment: @TheLQ Ever used Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and the hosting provider is bad and they should feel bad. Run away!